# How to get the log of apps that get started after starting the android device ?

Tags: android, boot, android-logcat

I am trying understand some concepts about android device startup ,I want to know that is there any way that I can get a log of applications that get started on device Boot-up ? How can we get that ?

I also want to know that, Is it possible to write an application that gets started at first after boot-up and stop certain apps from getting started on boot-up ?

Is there any IntentService that we have to write ? or this is not feasible unless we have root access ? Please help me in understanding this concepts.

Answer (score 1):

The device log is kept in a buffer, so the most recent entries will be there. If you are early enough before the buffer gets overwritten you will get it since the device booted.

You can access it using

```
$ adb logcat
```